# A candle burns for an hour, and $M$ burnt candles can make a new candle. For how long can $N$ candles keep the room lit?

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving, puzzle

There is a solution to a puzzle about candles, which I can't follow.

Here is the puzzle:

> Imagine there are $N$ candles. Each of the candles takes $1$ hour to burn. Out of burnt $M$ candles you can make one new candle. What is the longest you can keep the room lit?

The book I have gives such solution:

> If we take into account that after making a new candle, the number of burnt out candles reduces by $M-1$ and that finally we will still have one unused burnt out candle left, the answer can be computed using $$N + \frac{N-1}{M-1}$$

Specifically what is confusing me is why could we use $N-1$ as numerator and $M-1$ as denominator, based on this explanation:
"If we take into account that after making a new candle, the number of burnt out candles reduces by $M-1$ and that finally we will still have one unused burnt out candle left..." ?

Can someone help?
I am not a professional mathematician also and please explain in understandable terms, so far none of the answers have managed this.

Comment: The formula is not correct as is. If $N=5, M=4$ then the formula is not an integer.

Answer (score 3):

To make the text solution clearer, I will assume that $M - 1$ divides $N- 1$. Otherwise, it should be

$$N + \left\lfloor \frac{N-1}{M-1} \right\rfloor.$$

It should be clear that an optimal strategy has at any time only one candle used to lit up the room.

Hence, we may proceed as follows: First, we use up all the $N$ candles one by one. This gives us $N$ hours and $N$ burnt candles, corresponding to the first term.

Obviously, to keep going, we take $M$ of those burnt candles and make a new candle out of them. When that one is burnt out, we gained one extra hour and used up $M$ burnt candles which now resulted in $1$ burnt candle. Abstractly, and this is what is meant by the solution, *for every new hour we gain we use up $M-1$ burnt candles and are always left with (at least) one burnt up candle (namely, the last candle we lit)*.

Now, just to be really explicit here, let $H$ be the number of new hours gained. The above text says

$$N - H \cdot (M-1) \geq 1 \implies H \leq \frac{N-1}{M-1}.$$

And since $M-1$ divides $N-1$, the inequality can be attained.

**Further comments:** To expand on why the inequality turns into an equality, let's imagine that the first $N$ hours passed and we are left with those $N$ burnt candles. Let $H = (N-1) / (M -1)$. This is a positive integer since $M- 1 $ divides $N-1$. Now, leaving one candle aside, we can group the other $N-1$ burnt candles into $H$ groups of size $M-1$. For each of the $H$ groups, we can form a new candle with the set-aside candle and thus gain one hour from the new candle and are left again with a burnt candle. So, we gain in total $H$ more hours.

Comment: If it is how you say it is, the explanation in the book is pretty bad no? (n-1)/(m-1) doesn't immediately follow from what is written in the book, you have to get there via that inequality. The book says it like it follows immediately. Also in the solution (n-1)/(m-1) is directly used but you ended up with <=. Does that change anything?

Comment: Concerning the inequality, it at first only gives you the fact that $N + \frac{N-1}{M-1}$ is an upper bound on the number of hours. But again, because of the divisbility condition, you can get that it is in fact an equality by following the argument above. If you need further clarification on that, let me know.

Comment: Whether the solution is bad really depends on what the audience of the book is. If it is supposed to be an advanced book, then it is somewhat expected that they will leave simple calculations out. I will say though that the solution is very compressed even by those standards.

Comment: "because of the divisbility condition, you can get that it is in fact an equality by following the argument above."- why divisibility implies equality? no this is not advanced book :(

Comment: I expanded on that in my answer.

Comment: Let's follow like this. 1) You burn N candles and get N hours. 2) Now you have N burnt candles 3) Now you take out one burnt candle for some reason. 4) You have N-1 burnt candles now and you divide them on M-1 and get say H 5) Now you have H new candles and also one burnt candle from step 3. So what ? How do you proceed now?

Comment: Let's further discuss in the chatroom.

Comment: I added an slightly different approach below. I struggled to show that my answer was the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) := \lfloor x/M \rfloor + \text{mod}(x, M)$. This function counts how many burnt candles are created from lighting $x$ new candles.

Therefore, the total number of hours we can light the room is
$$N+\lfloor N/M \rfloor + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{f^{\circ i}(N)}M \right \rfloor$$

All that is left to prove is

$$\left \lfloor \frac{N-1}{M-1} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac N M \right \rfloor + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{f^{\circ i}(N)}M \right \rfloor$$

but

$$\left \lfloor \frac{N-1}{M-1} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac N M \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{\lfloor N/M \rfloor + \text{mod}(N,M)}M \right \rfloor + \sum_{i=2}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{f^{\circ i}(N)}M \right \rfloor$$

if and only if

$$\left \lfloor \frac{N-1}{M-1} \right \rfloor - \left \lfloor \frac {N + \lfloor N/M \rfloor} M \right \rfloor = \sum_{i=2}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{f^{\circ i}(N)}M \right \rfloor$$

Now, can you apply the trick recursively to prove the recurrence?

Comment: What could $f^{\circ i}$ possibly be?

Comment: @copper.hat just $i$ compositions of $f$

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of how many hours can you burn N candles. And how quickly
are new candles added to the "pool" of candles.

When M divides N exactly.
N=4, M=2, t=0
N=3, M=2, t=1
N=3, M=2, t=2
N=2, M=2, t=3
N=2, M=2, t=4
N=1, M=2, t=5
N=1, M=2, t=6
N=0, M=2, t=7

When M doesn't divide N exactly.
N=3, M=2, t=0
N=2, M=2, t=1
N=1, M=2, t=2
N=1, M=2, t=3
N=0, M=2, t=4

In general,
t = f(N,M) = N + floor(N/M)

Depending on your definition of the floor function. You'll notice the positive variant here looks very familiar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients

and in fact it's this more generally. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%27s_identity

If you replace floor(N/M) with the appropriate definition you'll get
t = f(N, M) = N + (N-1)/(M-1)

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of an addendum to @MXXZ's answer. I obtained an ostensibly different result using a another approach and was a little perplexed until I could show them equivalent.

An important point is that when we end, we have at least one (and fewer than $m$) burned candles.

Suppose that we gain $H$ new hours, then we have burned $N+H$ candles and in doing so made $H$ new candles. Hence we must have
$H = \lfloor {N+H \over m} \rfloor = {N+H \over m} - {k \over m}$, with $k \in \{0,...,m-1\}$.

Since we end with at least one burned candle, we see that $k \in \{1,...,m-1\}$.

Equivalently, $(m-1)H = N-k = N-1 - (k-1)$ or
$(k-1) + (m-1)H = N-1$, or
${k-1 \over m-1} + H = {N -1 \over m-1}$. Since $k-1 \in \{0,...,m-2\}$, we
see that $H = \lfloor {N-1 \over m-1} \rfloor$ which is the same as @MXXZ's answer.